# Is it possible for [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] to cache values even after deleting the app?

Tags: ios6, nsuserdefaults

I'm remotely trouble-shooting an issue where it appears as if even after installing the app, the user defaults don't get cleared. Here's what I mean:

```
BOOL myVar = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:key];

if (myVar) {
   NSLog(@"YES");
}else{
   NSLog(@"NO");
}
```

The first time I run a freshly installed app, I would expect it to return NO, until I explicitly set that key in NSUserDefaults.

However, it appears to be retuning YES even after deleting and re-installing.

Note that this is not a consistent behavior but does happen. iOS 6.0.1

Any thoughts here or am I looking in the wrong place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out that my bug wasn't related to user defaults, so this question is kind of irrelevant. But for the record, the answer is probably no, there's no caching after deleting the app.